# How to close all windows

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I would like to close all open windows. This will not minimize the windows but the script will close all windows even if it is minimized. Is there a way to do this in a batch program or powershell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use this in powershell:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | stop-process
```

-note: this close `powershell console` or `ise` too and can't end his job!

```
(get-process | ? { $_.mainwindowtitle -ne "" -and $_.processname -ne "powershell" } )| stop-process
```

this way only powershell windows is still alive but the last command in your script can be

```
stop-process powershell
```

note: this no affect tray icon minimized process.

EDIT:

to close 'control panel' on xp try this:

```
(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | where-object {$_.LocationName -eq "Control Panel"} | foreach-object {$_.quit()}
```

to close all explorer.exe windows:

```
(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}
```

Comment: Wow..this works. However it does not close the "control panel" window. Do you know how to close windows like those?

Comment: on windows 7 close 'control panel' too, in which o.s. are you trying?

Comment: I am using windows xp..any luck with this

Comment: The command "stop-process powershell" gives an error: "Stop-Process : Cannot bind parameter 'InputObject'. Cannot convert the "powershell" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Diagnostics.Process"."

Answer (score 0):

Today I was looking for that too and then wrote an autoit minimal script, send 99 times Keys:  Alt F4

1. install autoit3   [www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)
2. short version: file "end.au3"

   ```
    $loop=99
    While $loop
      $loop=$loop-1
      Send("!{F4}")    ; // send Keyboard Alt + F4 = close Window in Windows
    WEnd
   ```
3. run it in Autoit Editor with menu > tools > go
   or run it with F5
4. long version: make, in same folder as "end.au3" , a  "end.exe"  file and put on deskt..

   ```
    #Region ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
    #AutoIt3Wrapper_Outfile=end.exe
    #EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****

    ToolTip('au3    close all    EXIT ', 0, 0)  ;// litle box top left

    $loop=99
    While $loop
      $loop=$loop-1
      Send("!{F4}")    ;// send Keyboard Alt + F4 = close Window in Windows
    WEnd

    Exit
   ```